# How to know how many nodes in a Cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra

Given that I have the access to one node in the cluster, how can I know other nodes and their IPs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use nodetool command of Cassandra. Go to bin directory of Cassandra and then run the following command. There are many more options in nodetool but here I am giving an example of ring and status command.

```
./nodetool -h hostname -p port ring
```

or

```
./nodetool -h hostname -p port status
```

default node = localhost

default port = 7199